# Proper send file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-streams

Consider the following rather trivial middleware:

```
(req, res, next) => {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(req.filePath)

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => stream    
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('end', resolve)
    .pipe(res, { end: false })
    .on('error', reject)
    // 'close' is emitted if client prematurely disconnects.
    .on('close', resolve)
  res.end()
}
```

There are a few problems which I am unsure how to handle:

- If res has already emitted 'close' before this middleware runs it will be stuck.
- If res emits `close` or `error` how is the source stream cleaned up? `autoClose` will only run on `end` which will only run if all data has been read. However, if the target fails how is that propagated to the source? Should I always call `destroy` on the source stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import onFinished from 'on-finished'

(req, res, next) => {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(req.filePath)

  onFinished(res, () => stream.destroy && stream.destroy())

  if (onFinished.isFinished(res)) {
    return
  }

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => stream    
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('end', resolve)
    .pipe(res, { end: false })
    .on('error', reject)
    // 'close' is emitted if client prematurely disconnects.
    .on('close', resolve)
  res.end()
}
```